# ARM Error: Immediate expression requires a # prefix

Tags: assembly, arm, prefix

I have several errors but they are all the same, "immediate expression requires a # prefix". They are related to this kind of expressions (adding a bit of the code):

```
.sino:

                mov r3, FCmod(r0, #100)
                cmp r3, #0
                beq esZero
                b noEsZero
                .esZero:
                    mov r4, #1
                .noEsZero:
                    mov r4, #0
                mov r3, FCmod(r0, #400)
```

The error appears when I want to load the result of a function (FCmod) into a register. It would be great if you could help me! Thanks!

Comment: What is `FCmod(r0, #400)` supposed to mean?  What is `FCmod`?  Is it a macro?  Note that to call a function, you need to use the `bl` instruction.  There is no such thing as a function call operator in assembly.

Comment: An assembler isn't a compiler, each source line has to correspond to one machine instruction.  That obviously can't include calling a function and running all of its instructions, and putting the result somewhere you could `mov` from.  Look at compiler asm output if you want an example of how the syntax works.

Comment: Even if FCmod is a #define that is not assembly language, that is C you are doing some hybrid.  If it is an assembly language macro then it cant be used in that way.  Put a number there with a # prefix  #123

Comment: what assembler are you using, what command line are you using, assembly language is tool specific not target.

Comment: if FCmod is a function then preserve the link register and other registers, setup the calling registers, call the function then take the return value and do something with it.

Comment: what high level arm architecture are you going for?  aarch64?  aarch32 and of that arm or thumb?  (cortex-m, thumb with or without thumb 2 extensions)?   armv4t, armv6m armv7a, armv7m armv8?